# Can localization be done only through Code and not directly in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

Does IB not allow one to specify a localized key for components that display text instead of hardcoding the value?  For instance, if you want a UILabel to display internationalized text is the only way to do this via code?  Seems like such a PITA to have to set all your label text in code when you have a nice WYSIWYG editor like IB.  I think I had this feature back in VB5!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't normally need to write any code to localize your Interface Builder user interface (Xibs). What you do is create localized versions of these Xibs, with the help of XCode. In your XCode project, select a Xib, open the File Inspector (it's in the Utilities panel) and you'll see a Localization section in there. Click the + button and XCode will create a version for the language of your choice, which you can then localize by translating the text as well as resizing UI elements or do anything else you like.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess it surprises me that a UILabel have a "textKey" property along side it's text property where if the textKey prop is set, it draws derives its text property from a resource bundle.  That being said, I guess there is nothing stopping me from writing such a component eh?

Comment: Meant to say "doesn't have a "textKey" property", and "draws" should be deleted as well. Must have had too muh caffeine when I typed that comment.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way in Cocoa/AppKit is to localize the files you want to exist in different languages. But probably the only files you want make localized are your nib/xib files and your strings files.

Clafou has explained how you localize the nib files.

The strings files are files which contain key-value pairs. By calling functions like `NSLocalizedString` you can query them with the key you've set.

Apple has documented all these features. 
[Nib files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html)
[Strings files](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/StringsFiles.html)